# how to show entire context when using git-format patch master

Tags: git, format-patch

I'm trying to generate a diff using "git format-patch master".

This is fine, but I want the patch to show the full context (i.e the entire file with the differences).

Is there an argument I can pass to make that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found --unified=n , so I can just use a large number, and the whole context will appear :-)